# Ordered list of objects for template

Tags: python, django, orm

Trying to order my queryset. I know there is `order_by()` but ordering is defined by POST data, not anything in the DB.

```
sort----lookup-----display objects (darn, orderless)
1. Joe     \     
2. Fred     =>    {Fred, Joe, Marty} 
3. Marty   /
```

This is my view code I have so far...

```
from operator import itemgetter
#...

# Sorted Tuples! Now what?? (this is not used)
i1 = sorted([(k,v) for k,v in request.POST.items() if k[:2] == 'i_'], key=itemgetter(1))
e1 = sorted([(k,v) for k,v in request.POST.items() if k[:2] == 'e_'], key=itemgetter(1))

# Unsorted lists to use in ORM :/
i = [int(v) for k,v in request.POST.items() if k[:2] == 'i_']
e = [int(v) for k,v in request.POST.items() if k[:2] == 'e_']

# It's an orderless QuerySet...
i_students = Student.objects.filter(pk__in=i)
e_students = Student.objects.filter(pk__in=e)
```

If you have any ideas, let me know :) I would like to do this in the template...

```
<ol>
{% for s in i_students %}
     <li>{{ s }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

And have it display:

```
1. Joe
2. Fred
3. Marty
```

Answer (score 0):

This answered my question: http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/django-create-a-queryset-from-a-list-preserving-order.html

I get stuff like this from post:

```
i_0 -> 3
i_1 -> 26
i_2 -> 12
```

And I return the sorted objects like this:

```
i_tuples   = sorted([(k,v) for k,v in request.POST.items() if k[:2] == 'i_'], key=itemgetter(0))
i_pk_list  = [v for (k,v) in i_tuples]
clauses    = ' '.join(['WHEN id=%s THEN %s' % (pk, i) for i, pk in enumerate(i_pk_list)])
ordering   = 'CASE %s END' % clauses
i_students = Student.objects.filter(pk__in=i_pk_list).extra(
           select={'ordering': ordering}, order_by=('ordering',))
```

It's pretty messy, so if someone has a better solution for sorting QuerySets, let me know.